# Joining a m:n MySQL relation with every entity in own column

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm working on a web application to manage my books and I'm currently confronted with a problem I can't solve.

### Setup

- Each book has several information which are stored in the table `books`. The primary key is `bookId` and each book can be written by 1 or more authors.
- Each author has a `name` which together with the primary key `authorId` is stored in the table `authors`.  Every author can have written 1 or more books.
- Therefore I created a linking table `books_authors` where the `bookId` and the `authorId` are stored as foreign keys to `bookId` in `books` and `authorId` in `authors`.

See here a shortened version of the relevant tables:

```
books
+--------+-------+-------------+
| bookId | title | numberPages |
+--------+-------+-------------+
| 1      | Alpha | 100         |
| 2      | Beta  | 200         |
| 3      | Ceta  | 150         |
+--------+-------+-------------+

authors
+----------+----------+
| authorId | name     |
+----------+----------+
| 1        | John     | 
| 2        | Max      |   
| 3        | Gina     |
| 4        | Marry    |
+----------+----------+

books_authors
+--------+----------+
| bookId | authorId |
+--------+----------+
| 1      | 1        |
| 1      | 4        |
| 2      | 2        |
| 3      | 2        |
| 3      | 3        |
| 3      | 4        |
+--------+----------+
```

### Problem

I need a SQL statement now that gives me back one single table like the following. Every book should only have one row and all authors should be in seperate columns. And exactly this is the problem for me in finding a solution as sometimes a book has one or two or three or ... authors. So the statement should be "dynamic" in creating this "joined" table:

```
Joined Table
+--------+-------+-------------+---------+---------+---------+
| bookId | title | numberPages | author1 | author2 | author3 |
+--------+-------+-------------+---------+---------+---------+
| 1      | Alpha | 100         | John    | Marry   |         |
| 2      | Beta  | 200         | Max     |         |         |
| 3      | Ceta  | 150         | Max     | Gina    | Marry   |
+--------+-------+-------------+---------+---------+---------+
```

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: SQL queries return before-known columns. Writing a query is like drawing your result table ("Joined Table" in your request) and only leave the the rows empty; the columns are already known and titled. You cannot write a query with a flexible number of columns. What you could do is write a query with, say, one hundred author columns where most of the cells remain empty. But this is not how we write queries. What you have here is a mere display issue that should not be dealt with in SQL, but in your app or Webpage that displays the data. Or follow Tim's advice.

Comment: Okay, thank you for the explanation! I'll adapt the code in my application to extract the different authors from one column.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't like your current expected output, because in the future we may encounter a book which has more than 3 authors.  I suggest the following alternative:

```
SELECT
    b.bookId,
    b.title,
    b.numberPages,
    GROUP_CONCAT(a.name ORDER BY a.authorId) authors
FROM books b
LEFT JOIN books_authors ba
    ON b.bookId = ba.bookId
LEFT JOIN authors a
    ON ba.authorId = a.authorId
GROUP BY
    b.bookId;
```

This approach generates a CSV list of all authors of each book.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Tim! So there's no way of creating "dynamic" columns depending on how many authors there are? At the moment every row is saved as an book object in PHP and as every author should be clickable in the application separate I then would need to manually seperate them in the application, which is okay, but I thought I could bypass this with separated columns.

Comment: There is a way of creating dynamic columns, but it involves dynamic SQL, which I don't write very much of or often.  The version I gave above is easier to handle.

Comment: @Timo: And "dynamic SQL" means: write one query to retrieve the maximum number of authors, then use the retrieved number to create a query that contains as many columns. I suppose this is possible in MySQL stored procedures, but I am not sure. It is possible anyway with a programming language.

Comment: Okay, thank you! I'll try to implement this in my exisiting code.